# how to remove delete option when mouse hover on all users in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a project in wordpress.

In user options, when I select all users it shows a list of all users with `edit` / `delete` option. In my project, I want to remove delete option.

What do I need to do for this

Comment: I thing you have user list and selected user is delete and edit sure.

Comment: where it is? . backend or frontend?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet that hides the delete option from user with specific role (administrator in this case)

```
$role = get_role( 'administrator' ); // This is the user role
$role->remove_cap( 'delete_users' ); // This is the capability you remove
```

Refer to the codex for more info. Here are the two functions you need to use:

- remove_cap()
- get_role()
- roles and capabilities - https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#delete_users

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS to hide the `delete` option from appearing on hover. The following code adds custom styles the Admin area.

```
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_user_delete_option');

function hide_user_delete_option() {
  echo '<style>
    .users-php tr:hover .row-actions .delete{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
  </style>';
}
```